# Crystal Report using between but only 1 parameter is showing when Entering date values

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a formula in crystal reports that uses a year period to select its date range.

I want to edit it to bring back a range rather than just a single period.

However it is not giving me the option when entering values to give two parameters.

Current Code:

```
{PDP_ACC_PERIODS__.ACC_PERIOD} in {?ACC_PERIOD} to {?ACC_PERIOD}
```

But there is only one box to enter this, not two (as in from and too).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an identical parameter called ACC_PERIOD2 that looks at the same field, then added it in the selection expert as.

```
ACC_PERIOD

is between      {?ACC_PERIOD}
                {?ACC_PERIOD2}
```